# Dynamo QuerySpec with GSI

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

My Table schema is

virtual_key(hashKey)
actual_key (GSI)

Now I am trying to query index based on my actual_key like below

```
  final QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
        .withHashKey("actual_key", "1234");
  final Index index = table.getIndex("actual_key");
  final ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> result = index.query(spec);
```

I am pretty sure that item 'actual_key:1234' does exists in my table but I am getting a empty result set.
Note: I even tried

```
final QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
     .withKeyConditionExpression("actual_key = :v_key")
      .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":v_key","1234"));
```

I don't understand where I am making a mistake? and
can we use '.withHashKey' for GSI?

Comment: Can you show your data? Screenshot or something? And describe table output.

Answer (score 0):

```
QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("actual_key = :actualKey")
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
        .withString(":actualKey","1234"));

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(spec);
Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator(); 
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next().toJSONPretty());
}
```